Electron ready event fire Twice?
I'm building an electron app and when testing the app i wnated to minify the main.js using UglifyJS and the ready event in the minified version fire twice for some reason,
the main code is fine when i run it, it's just the minified version that does the bug.
uglify command uglifyjs src/electron/main.js -o src/electron/main.min.js --compress drop_console=true,passes=3 --mangle --module
main.js:
import { app, BrowserWindow as Window, WebContentsView as View } from "electron/main";
import { showNotification, setupTray, handleProtocolUrl } from "../supervisor/supervisor.js"
import { config as denv } from "dotenv"; denv();
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs";


/** @type {Protocol} */ export const __appProtocol = 'myapp';
/** @type {Path} */ const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;
global.win = null;
global.app = app;


// Ensure only a single instance of the app is running
const gotLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

if (!gotLock) {
    app.quit();
} else {
    if (app.isPackaged) {
        app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(__appProtocol);
    } else {
        app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(__appProtocol, process.execPath, [
            path.resolve(process.argv[1]),
        ]);
    }

    app.on('second-instance', (evt, argv) => {
        // for xml notification handling
        const url = argv.find(arg => arg.startsWith(`${__appProtocol}://`));
        url ? handleProtocolUrl(url) : null;
        windowExist();
    });

    app.whenReady().then(() => {
        console.log('App is ready');

        // Check if the app was started with --supervisor
        const isSupervisor = process.argv.includes('--supervisor');
        if (!isSupervisor) {
            console.log('not supervised')
            windowExist();
        }
        setupTray();

        const url = process.argv.find(arg => arg.startsWith(`${__appProtocol}://`));
        url ? handleProtocolUrl(url) : null;

        // test
        showNotification();
    });

    app.on('open-url', (evt, url) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        handleProtocolUrl(url);
    });

}

export function createWindow() {
    global.win = new Window({
        width: 975,
        height: 660,
        title: 'Campus',
        icon: "./assets/icon.ico",
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        titleBarOverlay: {
            symbolColor: '#74b1be',
            color: '#2f3241',
            height: 55,
            ////width: 120,
        },
        webPreferences: {
            //devTools: false,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.cjs')
        }
    });

    global.win.webContents.setUserAgent(process.env.userAgent);

    // example
    const hiddenContent = new View();
    hiddenContent.webContents.setUserAgent(process.env.userAgent);
    hiddenContent.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600 });
    hiddenContent.webContents.loadURL('https://google.com/');

    //win.setContentView()
    global.win.loadURL('https://google.com/').catch(console.error);
    global.win.contentView.addChildView(hiddenContent)

    global.win.on('close', () => {
        global.win = null;
    });

    return global.win;
}

function windowExist() {
    !global.win ? global.win = createWindow() : global.win.show();
}

I event tryed switshing app.whenReady with app.once('ready') and same result
